# How to delete dynamically created consumer groups in spring boot app

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I have multiple instances of my spring boot app consuming from a kafka topic. Since I want all instances to get data from all partitions of this topic, I assigned different consumers groups for each instances which would be created dynamically when starting this application.

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaStreamConfig {
@Bean("provisioningStreamsBuilderFactoryBean")
  public StreamsBuilderFactoryBean myStreamsBuilderFactoryBean() {
    String myCGName = "MY-CG-" + UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    Properties streamsConfiguration = new Properties();
    streamsConfiguration.put(APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, myCGName); // setting consumer group name
    // setting other props
    StreamsBuilderFactoryBean streamsBuilderFactoryBean = new StreamsBuilderFactoryBean();
    streamsBuilderFactoryBean.setStreamsConfiguration(streamsConfiguration);
    return streamsBuilderFactoryBean;
  }
}
```

So every time an instance restarts or a new instance is created, a new consumer group is created. And this's the consumer which reads from my topic.

```
@Component
public class MyConsumer {
    @Autowired
    private StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder;

    @PostConstruct
    public void consume() {
      final KStream<String, GenericRecord> events = streamsBuilder.stream("my-topic");
      events
      .selectKey((key, record) -> record.get("id").toString())
      .foreach((id, record) -> {
          // some computations with the events consumed
      });
    }
}
```

Now because of these dynamically created consumer groups stay on, and since they're not used in my application once an instance restarts, these don't consume messages anymore and show a lot of lag and hence give rise to false alerts.

So I'd like to delete these consumer groups when the application shuts down with Kafka's AdminClient api. I was thinking of trying to delete it in a shutdown hook like in a method annotated with `@PreDestroy` inside **MyConsumer** class like this:

```
@PreDestroy
public void destroyMYCG() {
  try (AdminClient admin = KafkaAdminClient.create(properties)) {
    DeleteConsumerGroupsResult deleteConsumerGroupsResult = admin.deleteConsumerGroups(Collections.singletonList(provGroupName));
    KafkaFuture<Void> future =  deleteConsumerGroupsResult.all();
    future.whenComplete((aVoid, throwable) -> {
      System.out.println("EXCEPTION :: " + ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(throwable));
    });
  }
  System.out.println(getClass().getCanonicalName() + " :: DESTROYING :: " + provGroupName);
}
```

but I'm getting this exception if I tried that and consumer groups still shows up in the list of consumer groups:

> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: The AdminClient thread is not accepting new calls.

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

1. IMHO this is logical mistake to create consumer group with UUID. Logically if the same process restarts, it is the same app - the same consumer. You will solve your problem giving good consumer groups names related to what logically do the app.
2. I would delete consumer groups on the server side, having "GC" set on certain level of lag.

Again consumer group is not application id. It is not intended to be randomly created.
And honestly spoken I not sure what kind of problem do you solve doing this.
Because in fact by saying that consumer group is random, you say my code is doing random things and I have no clue what happens in message processing.
We have very complex Kafka message processing and always there is better or worse name for the process, but at least exist one, which is not random.

Comment: it's the same application, but there'll be multiple instances spawned for the same application. So in order for all instances of my application to read from all partitions, I created a separate CG for each instance that's created, as I've already mentioned in my question.

Comment: I think, you mix something. You do not need to care about partitions. Why you do this? Number of partitions has nothing to do with consumer groups. Number of partitions is upper limit of paraller processing. Having many consumer groups hanging on the same topic you will read the same message in all consumers independently on partitions. In the case, when you have more consumer groups than partitions, you will wait for processing. Can you describe your architecture? BTW - you do not need to have consumer per partition. There is only very weak relation between those two.

Answer (score 0):

Using UUID as the consumer goup name is terrible.You can definition a final str as consumer goup name for each spring boot app.

Comment: it's the same application, but there'll be multiple instances spawned for the same application. So in order for all instances of my application to read from all partitions, I created a separate CG for each instance that's created, as I've already mentioned in my question.

Comment: You can use the same consumer group for all instances.Create a consumer goup at kafka server and as config set it to properties when you create consumer.

Comment: so each consumer in a consumer group subscribes to a bunch of partitions, so that they cover all partitions among themselves, right? so if I want a particular instance of my application to get all messages from all partitions, then don't I have to make sure that this consumer is the only one in that consumer group?

Comment: Yes, if consumers more than partitions, some consumer will sub 0 partition, consumers less than partitions,  some consumer will sub more than 1 partition

Comment: "if I want a particular instance of my application to get all messages from all partitions",  for this you need to use distribute lock make sure just one instance create consumer success that which instance do you want.

Comment: since I want all my consumers for this application to get data from all partitions, I had to generate group name on the fly.

Comment: If your application instance ip is changeless.You can use for example "consumer_goup_{ip}" as goup name. When you create goup,first check this group if exist, if true do nothing, if false create a goup by "consumer_goup_{ip}" this name.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, `deleteConsumerGroups` method will delete consumerGroups asynchronously and before that your application was shutdown and adminClient also disconnected. So that's why it's throwing AdminClient's thread is not accepting new calls.

To avoid this issue you can try synchronous call to delete consumerGroups.

```
  DeleteConsumerGroupsResult deleteConsumerGroupsResult = kafkaAdminClient.deleteConsumerGroups(kafkaConsumerGroups);
  try {
    deleteConsumerGroupsResult.all().get();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    log.error("Received exception while deleting consumerGroups: {}, {}", e.getMessage(),
            ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
  }
```